# laravel 4 , AVG and COUNT inside a join query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to execute a query with avg and count inside the rows result, something like that :

```
SELECT r.id, avg( p.puntuacio ), count(p.puntuacio)
FROM receptes AS r, puntuacio_receptes_usuaris AS p
WHERE r.id = p.recepta_id
GROUP BY r.id
```

But I don't know can I do on Laravel because in Eloquent can't write avg or count inside a result row.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query Builder (Fluent) method:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('receptes as r, puntuacio_receptes_usuaris as p'))
        ->select(array('r.id', DB::raw('avg( p.puntuacio ) as avg_p'), DB::raw('count(p.puntuacio) as count_p')))
        ->where('r.id', DB::raw('p.recepta_id'))
        ->groupBy('r.id')
        ->get();
```

This should work without any problem, but if you want to do it with your Eloquent model, I recommend using `JOIN` instead of using two tables in `FROM`.

You can access the avg and count results by accessing `avg_p` and `count_p`.

**Note**:

- `DB::raw()` instructs Laravel not to escape what's within, [see the doc](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions).

Comment: It works!!!! thank you so much, but I have a doubt because when I try to access to the elements in the array, for example {{Puntuacio::mitjanaTotesReceptes()[0]->id}}
Only can access to id but I don`t know how can access the other elements like avg or count, if I execute the sql query the columns are: id , avg(p.puntuacio) and count(p.puntuacio)

Comment: Updated the answer for you.

Comment: thanks a lot!!! but...
like {{Puntuacio::mitjanaTotesReceptes()[0]->avg_p}} ???
Because when I use it shows an error say: "Undefined property: stdClass::$avg_p"

Comment: Can you please `var_dump(Puntuacio::mitjanaTotesReceptes()[0]);` and post it on pastebin?

Comment: Sorry Usman, a little question, it works but the result of avg returns numbers like 8.0000 but without decimal numbers, in migrations p.puntuacio is a integer, is necessary to change the migrations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DB::raw()` to create a raw expression if you need to use things which would otherwise be escaped by Eloquent.

Refer to the [documentation on raw expressions](http://four.laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) for some examples.